# Discount rate with if statement

Tags: java

im trying to apply a discount system into one of my programs.
Im very new to programming so I'm sorry for the beginner questions!

Okay so this is my current discount formula

```
double discount = total - (total*number*0.025);
```

Basically will get a 2.5% discount off the total cost for each package (number).
Im wanting this to stop at 30%, so no discount can be greater than 30% off.

This is what I tried

```
if(discountOne >= totalOne/3) {
      discountOne = totalOne*0.33;
}
```

However it didnt work.
Any help is much appreciated! Also if theres a better formula I should be using feel free to let me know.
Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to say that you add a 2.5% discount on every product, and once the total of the number of discounts (i.e. products being added) is 30% (i.e. 12 products), you no longer want to apply a discount?

Comment: Do you want 30%, or 33.333333%...? You say one thing but write another.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate maximum discount possible
i.e. maxDiscount -> 30% of Total

Then compare your discount by checking discount <= maxDiscount

Comment: Yup sure. Just try breaking your calculation by arriving at a maximum discount value possible i.e. 30% in amount and then compare it with the discount you are giving.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of `discount` is wrong. Let's say you have 4 items, so that's a 2.5*4% discount, or a 10% discount. Let's say the total cost is $200. Then the discount is 10% of $200, i.e. $200*0.1 i.e. $20. It is *not* $200 - $20 i.e. $180.

Therefore, you need to calculate it using this formula instead.

```
double discount = total * number * 0.025;
```

You can make this much easier on yourself by calculating the percent in advance...

```
double percentDiscount = number * 0.025;
double discount = total * percentDiscount;
```

Now it becomes simpler to avoid rounding errors and other logic problems just be checking `percentDiscount` alone.

```
double percentDiscount = number * 0.025;
if (percentDiscount > 0.3) percentDiscount = 0.3;
double discount = total * percentDiscount;
```

You can be precognizant of your arithmetic, as Selkuk points out, by checking `if (number > 12)` instead, since 30% / 2.5% is 12.

```
double percentDiscount = ((number > 12) ? 12 : number) * 0.025;
double discount = total * percentDiscount;
```

You could also use `Math.min` instead of these conditionals and ternary expressions I use.

Trivially, the price after discount is just `total - discount`.

Comment: Yes my next line is price = total - discount :)

Comment: @user134613 That would make `price` $20. Please post your entire code.